# Thread of a Runnable is not being destroyed after execution

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, executorservice

My code base is quite big, so I will try to put it here as concise as possible.

I am under the assumptions that if a `Runnable` finishes execution inside a `Thread`, that then both the `Thread` and the `Runnable` will be destroyed, as the code inside the `Runnable` is linear code, well maybe some function calls, but definitely no loops.

The issue is that the `Thread` does remain to be running, while I think it should not.

Creation of the `RunnableProcessor`:

```
Controller.getInstance().getNamedThreadFactory().addThreadName("EST: " + runnableProcessor.toString());
Controller.getInstance().getExecutorService().execute(runnableProcessor);
```

The `RunnableProcessor` class:

```
public class RunnableProcessor<T> implements Runnable {
    private final Processor<T> processor;
    private final T object;

    public RunnableProcessor(final Processor<T> processor, final T object) {
        this.processor = processor;
        this.object = object;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        processor.process(object);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RunnableProcessor(\"" + processor + "\", \"" + object.toString() + "\")";
    }
}
```

An example of such a `Processor`, namely `InputProcessor`:

```
public class InputProcessor implements Processor<File> {
    private static final String PDF = "pdf";

    @Override
    public void process(File file) {
        if (new CustomPath(file).getExtension().equalsIgnoreCase(PDF)) {
            processPdf(file);
        }
        else {
            processImage(file);
        }
    }

    private void processPdf(final File file) {
        System.out.println("Processing " + file.toString());
        FileEditor.convert(file);
        Utils.move(file.toPath(), new File(Controller.DONE_URL + File.separator + file.getName()).toPath());
        System.out.println("Processed");
    }

    private void processImage(final File file) {
        //Skew detection
        System.out.println("Rotating " + file.toString());
        SkewDetector skewDetector = new SkewDetector(file);
        File rotatedFile = skewDetector.detect();
        Utils.move(rotatedFile.toPath(), new File(Controller.ROTATED_INPUT_URL + File.separator + rotatedFile.getName()).toPath());
        System.out.println("Rotated");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "InputProcessor";
    }
}
```

Nothing in the code blocks the execution, that is in this case the specific strings `Processed` or `Rotated` are all being printed to `System.out`, and after that the specific `Thread` still does not die. This is for example one of the threads still being alive, even though execution of the `Runnable` finished, the name is: `EST: RunnableProcessor("InputProcessor", "D:\OCR\renamed_input\682-converted.tiff")`.

The behaviour of the thread, over two minutes measured, seems interesting though: It follows this sequence: Shortly running, shortly being monitored, long running, quick monitor, short running, very long wait, relative short running, very long wait, relative short running, waiting (until eternity?).

Can anyone help figure out what exactly is going on?

Comment: What package does your `Controller` belong to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using an executor service. While it could be implemented to create new threads for each task it can, and apparently in your case is, implemented using a thread pool that keeps threads waiting for new tasks to run. According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) this is done for better performance.

You should not depend on the inner workings of the executor service anyway. If you need to be notified when your task is done I'd recommend to monitor the task or the/a wrapper.

If you want to create a new wrapper and seem to be polling (the thread status) anyway it can be as simple as:

```
void run() {
    innerRunner.run();  // the wrapped runner
    doneFlag = true;    // a boolean indicating the status
}
```

Comment: Ah so threads never get destroyed by themselves (only `ExecutorService` controls that... Then perhaps I am implementing it wrongly, ie. using names that make no sense in this context.

Comment: Now I get what you're up to with your names. That probably won't work since it is explicitly the ExecutorService's job to manage its threads.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to call

```
Controller.getInstance().getExecutorService().shutdown();
Controller.getInstance().getExecutorService().awaitTermination();
```

To shutdown your thread pool.

Comment: Should I be using both of the statements, or just one of them depending on how I want to shutdown the executor service?

Comment: In most cases you would need both - the first one signals to stop accepting any new jobs and continues execution, so i.e. if it is an end of your `main()` your app will exit. The second waits for unfinished jobs to end.

Answer (score 0):

You use the thread pool that create fixed number of threads. Thread pool reuses created threads for tasks execution(`Runnable, Callable`). You can't explicit destroy threads, because threads are manageable thread pool.

As you said @Andrey Chaschev you should call it:

```
Controller.getInstance().getExecutorService().shutdown();
Controller.getInstance().getExecutorService().awaitTermination();
```

for threads termination.